# Unknown variable

Tags: java, variables

Why is the variable `eachLetter` unknown when I reference it in the second loop?

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        String myName = ("Yourname");
        int maxLength = myName.length() - 1;
        for (int loops = 0; loops <= maxLength; loops++) {

            char[] eachLetter = myName.toCharArray();

            System.out.print(loops);
            System.out.print(eachLetter[loops]);
        }
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("next loop");
        for (int loops = maxLength; loops <= 0; loops--) {
            System.out.print(loops);
            System.out.print(eachLetter[loops]);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Becaus you define it inside the for loop, it's not visible outside the loop

Answer (score 2):

Because it lives only in first loop scope. You have to declare it before you enter into first loop.

```
char[] eachLetter = new char[maxLength];
for (int loops=0; loops <= maxLength; loops++) {
    eachLetter = myName.toCharArray();
}
for (int loops= maxLength; loops<=0; loops--) {
    (..)
}
```

Comment: Yep, I didn't removed declaration from loop. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

First, lets format your code so it's legible:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String myName = ("Yourname");
    int maxLength = myName.length() - 1;
    for (int loops = 0; loops <= maxLength; loops++) {

        char[] eachLetter = myName.toCharArray();

        System.out.print(loops);
        System.out.print(eachLetter[loops]);
    }
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("next loop");
    for (int loops = maxLength; loops <= 0; loops--) {
        System.out.print(loops);
        System.out.print(eachLetter[loops]);

    }
}
```

Now, in Java - like in VBA with `Option Explicit` - each variable must be **declared in scope** to be **visible**.

In Java scope is within curly brackets so:

```
{
    char[] thing = ...
    thing[i]...
}
//error
thing[i]
```

This is because the second `thing[i]` is *outside* of the curly brackets.

In your example you declare `eachLetter` *within* the `for` loop - each iteration has its own instance. You are trying to access it *outside* of the loop. The only way to do this is to declare it in a **wider scope** - i.e. in the next set of curly brackets up, the method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String myName = ("Yourname");
    int maxLength = myName.length() - 1;
    char[] eachLetter = ...
    for (int loops = 0; loops <= maxLength; loops++) {
        eachLetter = myName.toCharArray();
```

But the real question is *why* you are doing this. Every time the `for` loop iterates you get a **different** `char[]`. You will only be able to access the *last one* from outside the loop.

Comment: Thanks for the responses....I thought it was something like that but let trying to !over the {} down, rather than the variable up.....and as for why? Why not? Seriously, trying to just mess around....but want the second loop to print my name backwards